# ¿Cómo puedo escribir un carácter múltiples veces con Bash y dibujar un cuadrado?

Tags: bash, shell-script, printf

Necesito que esté script realice un cuadrado de *, pero que solo los coloque en el borde y no dentro. Aquí está mi script.

```
echo cuanto asteriscos por lado quieres?
read m
for ((j=0;j<m;j++)) do
    for((i=1;i<m;i++)) do
        echo -n "*"
    done
    echo "*"
done
```

Solo díganme qué le agrego o qué le quito, porfa.

Answer (score 2):

### Posible solución interesante con explicación práctica

Crearemos tres (03) funciones para dividir el programa en piezas más pequeñas que describan claramente las acciones que van a a realizar durante su ejecución. Las funciones son `asteriscos`, `espacios` y `escribir`, que serán explicadas a continuación:

- **`asteriscos`:** escribirá en una línea la cantidad de asteriscos solicitados al usuario. Cada vez que esta función sea llamada volverá a escribir la misma cantidad de asterisco solicitada previamente.
- **`espacios`:** rellenará una línea con un asterisco en la primera columna, seguida de espacios en blanco, finalizando con un asterisco en la última columna.
- **`escribir`:** esta función se encargará de llamar a las funciones `asteriscos` y `espacios` en función del punto de partida y finalización del bucle. Es decir, en la **primera y última** iteración del bucle se ejecutará la función `asteriscos`. La función `espacios` se ejecutarán en todas las iteraciones, excepto, en las iteraciones correspondientes a la ejecución de la función `astericos`.

Si deseas ampliar un poco sobre las funciones, esto le podrá interesar:

- [Cómo usar funciones en Bash | Ubunlog](https://ubunlog.com/como-usar-funciones-en-bash/)
- [Crea y usa funciones de Bash | Like Geeks](https://likegeeks.com/es/funciones-de-bash/)

### Vamos a la práctica:

Solicitemos al usuario los datos requeridos:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
clear

# Solicitamos los datos al usuario:
echo -n "¿Cuánto asteriscos por lado quieres? => "
read m
```

### Definición de funciones:

Ahora, definamos las funciones que hemos descrito en esta respuesta.

#### Función `asteriscos`:

```bash
asteriscos() {
  # En esta función hemos definido un bucle para que itere 
  # desde el 0 a $1, siendo $1 el argumento de la función:
  for (( a = 0; a < $1; a++ )); do
    echo -n "* " # Se rellenan de asteriscos solo en una línea
  done

  # Al finalizar el bucle, realizamos un saldo de línea:
  echo ""
}
```

De acuerdo a lo observado anteriormente se ha definido una función que contiene un bucle y un salto de línea. El bucle itera desde `0` hasta `$1`, siendo `$1` el argumento de la función que tomará un valor numérico introducido por el usuario.

#### Función `espacios`:

```bash
espacios() {
  for (( b = 1; b <= $1; b++ )); do
    if [[ $b == 1 || $b == $1 ]]; then
      echo -n "* " # Se colocará asteriscos en la primera y última iteración.
    else
      echo -n "  " # De lo contrario, se rellenarán de espacios en blanco.
    fi
  done

  # Salto de línea:
  echo ""
}
```

En la función `espacios`, a diferencia de la función `asteriscos` se evalúa dentro del bucle si el iterador `b` es `1` o igual al valor numérico del argumento de la función para colocar los asteriscos, o si por el contrario, colocar espacios en blanco. Dicho de otra manera, se evalúa cuándo colocar asteríscos y espacios en blanco en una línea.

#### Función `escribir`:

```bash
escribir() {
  # Se evalúan sus argumentos para determinar cuándo 
  # es conveniente llamar a la función «asteriscos» o
  # «espacios» en función de un contexto dado:
  if [[ $1 == 1 || $1 == $2 ]]; then
    asteriscos $2
  else
    espacios $2
  fi
}
```

Se puede observar que la función escribir determina cuándo deben llamarse las funciones `asteriscos` y `espacios` en un contexto dado.

Ya definida las funciones podemos definir un bucle que itere la cantidad de asteriscos que el usuario desee:

```bash
for (( i = 1; i <= $m; i++ )); do
  # Donde $i es el iterador del bucle y $m 
  # el número ingresado por el usuario:
  escribir $i $m
done
```

### Vamos a armar todo el código:

Vamos a asumir que el siguiente código está contenido en un archivo llamado `asteriscos`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
clear

echo -n "¿Cuánto asteriscos por lado quieres? => "
read m

asteriscos() {
  # En esta función hemos definido un bucle para que itere 
  # desde el 0 a $1, siendo $1 el argumento de la función:
  for (( a = 0; a < $1; a++ )); do
    echo -n "* " # Se rellenan de asteriscos solo en una línea
  done

  # Al finalizar el bucle, realizamos un saldo de línea:
  echo ""
}

espacios() {
  for (( b = 1; b <= $1; b++ )); do
    if [[ $b == 1 || $b == $1 ]]; then
      echo -n "* " # Se colocará asteriscos en la primera y última iteración.
    else
      echo -n "  " # De lo contrario, se rellenarán de espacios en blanco.
    fi
  done

  # Salto de línea:
  echo ""
}

escribir() {
  # Se evalúan sus argumentos para determinar cuándo 
  # es conveniente llamar a la función «asteriscos» o
  # «espacios» en función de un contexto dado:
  if [[ $1 == 1 || $1 == $2 ]]; then
    asteriscos $2
  else
    espacios $2
  fi
}

for (( i = 1; i <= $m; i++ )); do
  # Donde $i es el iterador del bucle y $m 
  # el número ingresado por el usuario:
  escribir $i $m
done
```

Para ejecutarlo, debemos otorgar primero los permisos de ejecución:

```bash
usuario@usuario:~/$ chmod +x asteriscos
```

Esto es, asumiendo que hemos creado el archivo `asteriscos` y guardado el código expuesto en esta respuesta en él.

Luego, lo ejecutamos:

```bash
usuario@usuario:~/$ ./asteriscos
```

Luego de ejecutado el archivo, esto es lo que obtenemos:

```
¿Cuánto asteriscos por lado quieres? => 15
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
*                           * 
*                           * 
*                           * 
*                           * 
*                           * 
*                           * 
*                           * 
*                           * 
*                           * 
*                           * 
*                           * 
*                           * 
*                           * 
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
usuario@usuario:~/$
```

Si bien, parece ser una solución interesante al problema, es posible que hayan soluciones muchos mejores de las consideradas acá en esta respuesta.

Para finalizar, les comparto un enlace para que puedan correr el código en un emulador en línea de Bash y probar sus resultados: [Repl.it - asteriscos](https://repl.it/@DavidEE1/asteriscos)

Comment: Nótese que `printf` ya permite escribir un carácter múltiples veces. Lo explico en mi respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/319968/83

Comment: Dicho lo cual,.muy bien por modularizarlo y explicarlo tan bien

Answer (score 2):

Usa el hecho que `printf '*%.0s' {1..n}` imprime `n` asteriscos, todos seguidos. Como `{..}` no permite variables, debemos usar `seq` para hacerlo dinámico:

```
$ printf '*%.0s' $(seq 5)
*****
$ printf '*%.0s' $(seq 10)
**********
```

Todo junto:

```
printf '*%.0s' $(seq $1)
printf '\n'
for ((i=2;i<$1;i++))
do
    printf '*'
    printf ' %.0s' $(seq $(($1-2)))
    printf '*\n'
done
printf '*%.0s' $(seq $1)
printf '\n'
```

Ejemplos de salida:

```
$ bash cuadrado.sh 5
*****
*   *
*   *
*   *
*****
$ bash cuadrado.sh 7
*******
*     *
*     *
*     *
*     *
*     *
*******
```

Comment: Una forma corta e interesante de resolver el tema de los asteriscos. Interesante aporte.

Answer (score 0):

Para tener un cuadrado, mejor que el bucle de `i` también empieza con 0. Después, añadir un test "`if` `j` diferente de `0` y diferente de `m-1` y también `i` diferente de `0` y diferente de `m-1`" imprime un asterisco. Y `else`  imprime un espacio.

Para mejorar, se puede cambiar los bucles para ir desde `1` a `m` en vez de desde `0` a `m-1`.

Answer (score 0):

Otra solución para tu problema podría ser la siguiente.

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Cantidad: " cantidad

for (( i = 1; i <= $cantidad; ++i )); do
    [[ $i -eq 1 || $i -eq $cantidad ]] && caracter='*' || caracter=' '

    cadena="${cadena}*$(printf "$caracter%.0s" $(seq 1 $((cantidad - 2)) ) )*\n"
done

echo -en "$cadena"
```

Lo que hago es construir renglones de esta forma `*+(n-2)carcater+*+salto_de_linea` y los voy pegando concatenándolos.

Pero primero reviso si el caracter el renglón es el primero o el último. Si es alguno de estos, entonces el caracter de en medio será un asterisco, si no lo es entonces es un espacio.

Al final los imprimo interpretando la cadena `\n` como salto de línea sin el salto de linea por default con `echo -ne`

El resultado de este script es semejante a los anteriores.

```
$ ./cuadrado.sh
Cantidad: 6
******
*    *
*    *
*    *
*    *
******
```